# how to kill uWSGI process

Tags: uwsgi

So I have finally gotten nginx + uWSGI running successfully for my Django install

however the problem I am having now is when I make changes to the code I need to restart the uWSGI process to view my changes

I feel like I am running the correct command here (i am very new to linux as well btw):

```
uwsgi --stop /var/run/uwsgi.pid
uwsgi --reload /var/run/uwsgi.pid
```

I get no error when I run these commands however my old code is still what loads

I also know its not a coding issue because I ran my django app in its development server and everything ran fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to signal reloading of application data is to use the `--touch-reload` option. Sample syntax on a .ini fine is:

```
touch-reload /var/run/uwsgi/app/myapp/reload
```

Where `myapp`is your application name. `/var/run/uwsgi/app` is the recommended place for such files (could be anywhere). The `reload` file is an empty file whose timestamp is watched by uwsgi, whenever it changes (by, for example, using `touch`) uWSGI detects that change and restarts the corresponding uWSGI application instance.

So, whenever you update your code you should touch the file in order to update the in-memory version of the application. For example, on bash:

```
sudo touch /var/run/uwsgi/app/myapp/reload
```

Note `--reload` is an undocumented option on current uWSGI version.

Comment: when you say sample on an .ini file you do you mean place that touch reload line in the ini file? and what is the app/myapp structure coming from?

Comment: yes, this line should be added to the uWSGI .ini file corresponding to your application. If you use XML, YAML, JSON you'll need to use the correct syntax instead of .ini's `<var>=<value>` standard.

I use to place the `touch-reload` file under `/var/run/uwsgi/app/<app name>` but you may place it anywhere convenient to you, such as your home directory.

Comment: What is the touch-reload file you reference now???  As of right now I am thinking in my ini file `touch-reload /path/to/my/ini/file` however that does not make sense, i am assuming i need to create a touch-reload file?  what do i place in that file?

Comment: there is a unix command named `touch` which "touches" the date and time of the file. if you run `touch /path/to/your/touch/reload/file` uWSGI will detect the new timestamp and reload your .ini file. Touching the file is the way to communicate to uWSGI that you want your .ini files to reload (along your new source files).

Comment: Almost two years later I managed to understand @tareq question. My fault!
The touch-reload file is an arbitrary empty file and it may be anywhere, a good place for it is within /var/run subtree, like the suggested /var/run/uwsgi/<appname>/reload. When we run touch over it its timestamp changes to the current datetime, uwsgi detects this change and reloads the corresponding uwsgi application instance.